# How do I do a regexp search against a Mandarin string?

Tags: regex, internationalization

How do I do a regexp search against a Mandarin string?

Comment: We need a lot more information to help you. Your environment, the language you are using and the api at least.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No different that against any other string; of course it requires a language and a regexp library that correctly uses unicode for its strings and doesn't assume that a string is just a byte array interpreted as ASCII.

Answer (score 0):

In what language?  In PHP, use UTF-8 and the /u modifier.